# Rendering text from the localhost server

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

- When i fetch my text from localhost sometimes its getting displayed in textview and sometimes its not.
- I dont know what to do, but i had checked all my localhost server,**Database** Table its working fine in postman.
- But ,when i integrate with **android**  sometimes text is not getting displayed

  ```
  public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<RequestPackage, String, String> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();


  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(RequestPackage... params) {
      return RequestHttpURLConnection.getData(params[0]);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = null;


          switch (gridItemId) {
              case 0:
                  break;
              case 1: {
                  Chairmen_textView.setText(result);
              }
              break;
              case 2: {
                  Principal_textView.setText(result);
                 }  break;

              case 3:   try  {


                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                      String trust_title = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                      String trust_content = jsonObject1.getString("trust_content");
                      String college_details = jsonObject1.getString("college_details");
                      Trust_title_textView.setText(trust_title);
                      Trust_content_textView.setText(trust_content);
                      College_details_textView.setText(college_details);
                  }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } break;


              case 4: try {

                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                      String management = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                      String headline = jsonObject1.getString("headline");
                      String powers = jsonObject1.getString("powers");
                      String name = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                      String member_title = jsonObject1.getString("member_title");
                      String member_content = jsonObject1.getString("member_content");
                      String end_line = jsonObject1.getString("end_line");

                      Management_textView.setText(management);
                      Headline_textView.setText(headline);
                      Power_textView.setText(powers);
                      Name_textView.setText(name);
                      Member_title_textView.setText(member_title);
                      Member_content_textView.setText(member_content);
                      End_line_textView.setText(end_line);
                  }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }   break;

              case 5: try {

                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                      String quality_title = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                      String subtitle_vision = jsonObject1.getString("subtitle_vision");
                      String subtitle_vision_content = jsonObject1.getString("vision_content");
                      String subtitle_mission = jsonObject1.getString("subtitle_mission");
                      String subtitle_mission_content = jsonObject1.getString("mission_content");
                      String subtitle_quality_policy = jsonObject1.getString("subtitle_quality_policy");
                      String subtitle_quality_policy_content = jsonObject1.getString("quality_policy_content");


                      Quality_Title_textView.setText(quality_title);
                      Subtitle_vision_textView.setText(subtitle_vision);
                      Subtitle_vision_content_textView.setText(subtitle_vision_content);
                      Subtitle_mission_textView.setText(subtitle_mission);
                      Subtitle_mission_content_textView.setText(subtitle_mission_content);
                      Subtitle_quality_policy_textView.setText(subtitle_quality_policy);
                      Subtitle_quality_policy_content_textView.setText(subtitle_quality_policy_content);


                  }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }      break;
              case 6:try {

                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                      String location_title = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                      String location_content = jsonObject1.getString("location_content");
                      Location_title.setText(location_title);
                      Location_content.setText(location_content);


                  }

                   }catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } break;
          }
      }


     }
  ```

Comment: any exceptions' stacktraces in logcat?

Comment: Nope, nothing.. is this a right way to code in onPostExecute.

Comment: `case 0:
                break;`. There wil not be much displayed in this case dont you think?

Comment: You did not tell how your code flows. Which case is selected. The value of result.

Answer (score 0):

First I would wrap the try catch block around the switch to avoid code duplication. Second you are only catching jsonexception, try to replace this exception with a more general exception. Maybe this helps

Comment: It's been a while since I dealt with this, but you have two threads, the background thread and the main thread which renders the UI. 
Due to concurrency, the Textview sometimes might update in the UI thread (this is when you see text) and sometimes from the context of the background thread (this is when you don't see text updated). There is a method called "runOnUIThread" which takes a runnable as a parameter. Try to update your textview elements in this runnable/UIThread. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Very bad idea. That code should just display in onPostExecute.

Comment: @greenapps If I get you right, you mean rendering the text on the UI thread is a bad idea? Can you be more precise?